# Codeigniter email validation with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a registration form that I've written by codeigniter framework.
I use this code for email validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'valid_email|required');
```

While I haven't used jquery ajax, it was returning errors for invalid email address. But now with this ajax code, It accepts any input in email input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#add_staff input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
        var form_data = {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            username: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            passconf: $('#passconf').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            modir: $('#modir').val(),
            ajax: '1'

        };

        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('admin/add_user_validation'); ?>" ,
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data ,
            success: function(msg) {
                $('body').html(msg);
            }
        });
           return false;    
    });
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why are you doing this? if you are validating using Ajax/Jquery use client site validation.

Comment: @Vinie you know, because I use ajax, it does not refresh the page, so there is no difference to validate from server side or client side. What is your suggestion for client side validation? And what if a person change client codes form inspect element in browser? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on validation error on php page send following response

```
echo json_encode(array(array('status'=>false,'message'=>  validation_errors())));
```

and in jquery response

```
success: function(msg) {
$.each(eval(msg),function(i,item)
               {
                   if(item.status)
                   {
                       $("#result").empty().append(item.message); //on success

                    }else{
                         $("#result").empty().append(item.message); // on validation error

                        }                  

                });
}
```